# Vectorizing Skipgrams in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, scikit-learn

I want to try the skipgrams approach on my dataset. But I do not know how to vectorize it. For example, I have my cleaned document for which I got it's skipgrams. Now, how do I know vectorize it so that I can use it further for classification? I use sklearn for all the above purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question can be found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45997893/5312422

> To vectorize text with skip-grams in scikit-learn simply passing the
>   skip gram tokens as the vocabulary to CountVectorizer will not work.
>   You need to modify the way tokens are processed which can be done with
>   a custom analyzer. Below is an example vectorizer that produces
>   1-skip-2-grams,
>
> from toolz import itertoolz, compose from toolz.curried import map as
>   cmap, sliding_window, pluck from sklearn.feature_extraction.text
>   import CountVectorizer
>
> ```
> class SkipGramVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
>     def build_analyzer(self):    
>         preprocess = self.build_preprocessor()
>         stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
>         tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()
>         return lambda doc: self._word_skip_grams(
>                 compose(tokenize, preprocess, self.decode)(doc),
>                 stop_words)
>
>     def _word_skip_grams(self, tokens, stop_words=None):
>         # handle stop words
>         if stop_words is not None:
>             tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]
>
>         return compose(cmap(' '.join), pluck([0, 2]), sliding_window(3))(tokens)
> ```
>
> For instance, on this Wikipedia example,
>
> ```
> text = ['the rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain']
>
> vect = SkipGramVectorizer()
> vect.fit(text)
> vect.get_feature_names()
> ```
>
> this would vectorizer would yield the following tokens,
>
> ```
> ['falls on',  'in falls',  'mainly the',  'on plain',  'rain spain', 
> 'spain mainly',  'the in']
> ```